# Why aren't these arguments valid?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

```
//Block.h
#pragma once
class Block
{
 public:
    CRect pos;
    int num;

 public:
    Block(void);
   ~Block(void);
};
```

---

```
  //view class
  public:
  Block currentState[5];       // stores the current state of the blocks
```

---

```
 void CpuzzleView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{

 CpuzzleDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
 ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
 if (!pDoc)
    return;

//draw the 4 blocks and put text into them
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    pDC->Rectangle(currentState[i].pos);
            // i'm getting an error for this line:
    pDC->TextOut(currentState[i].pos.CenterPoint(), currentState[i].num);    
}


    pDC->TextOut(currentState[i].pos.CenterPoint(), currentState[i].num);
```

The error says that no instance of overloaded function CDC::TextOutW() matches the argument list . But the prototype for the function is:

```
     CDC::TextOutW(int x, int y, const CString &str )
```

all i've done is that instead of the 2 points i've directly given the point object returned by CenterPoint() ... shouldn't it work?

Comment: Why do you think this would work exactly?  The function takes two ints not whatever CenterPoint() returns.  And there are three arguments to the TextOut function, not two, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you didn't supplied arguments list correctly. Please read compiler error message carefully, it's usually helps to solve the problem.

```
TextOut(currentState[i].pos.CenterPoint(), currentState[i].num);
```

In this call you passed `CPoint` object and `int`. This is not correct, you need to pass `int`, `int` and `CString` (or `const char*` and `int` length).

To fix this you shall do something like this:

```
CString strState;
strState.Format("%d", currentState[i].num); // Or use atoi()/wtoi() functions
TextOut(currentState[i].pos.CenterPoint().x, currentState[i].pos.CenterPoint().x, strState);
```